# Validating a property in array in request.body using ValidatorJS

Tags: node.js, validation

Im using  [validatorJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validatorjs) in my nodeJs service for validation.

Below is my req.body structure

```
[
    {
        "accountType": 1.2,
        "series": "medium",
        //other properties here
    },
    {
        "accountType": 2,
        "series": "severe",
        //other properties here
    },
]
```

**Validation rule :**

```
const accountRule = {
    '*.accountType': 'required|numeric|min:0'
}
```

**Validation logic**

```
import Validator from '../validator';

public accountValidation = (req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {
        Validator(req.body, accountRule, {}, (err, isValid) => {
            if (!isValid) {
                //response logic here
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    };


`isValid` is always coming true, and not validating the accountType properties even if I pass incorrect types like
true, "Something", -2 ...
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to change the structure of my req.body like below

```
{ 
  "accountOb":
  [
    {
        "accountType": 1.2,
        "series": "medium",
        //other properties here
    },
    {
        "accountType": 2,
        "series": "severe",
        //other properties here
    },
  ]
}
```

Modified the rule to like below

```
const accountRule = {
    'accountOb.*.accountType': 'required|numeric|min:0'
}
```

Then the validation works fine. But I don't want to change the structure of my request.
Is there any way I can validate without wrapping the object over the request structure